# my very basic for loop for removing vowels from a text isn't working

Tags: python, cs50

I'm doing the CS50P course as my first course in python and in Problem set 2 there was a problem about removing vowels from a given text

I tried doing

```
Vowels = ["A", "a", "E", "e", "U", "u", "O", "o", "I", "i"]
inputs = input("input: ")
outputs = inputs
for x in Vowels:
    outputs.replace(x, "")
print(f"output: {outputs}")
```

but it didn't work
I've solved the problem in another way but I'm just curious why didn't my first attempt work

Comment: `.replace()` returns a _new_ string.  It does not modify the existing string.

Answer (score 1):

The replace function does not actually replace it, it just returns a string with the inputs replaced. So instead, you could write:

```python
Vowels = ["A", "a", "E", "e", "U", "u", "O", "o", "I", "i"]
inputs = input("input: ")
outputs = inputs
for x in Vowels:
    outputs = outputs.replace(x, "")
print(f"output: {outputs}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reassign the value, after replacing the vowel. So your code will be

```py
outputs = outputs.replace(x, "")
```

The replace function doesn't modify the original string, instead it returns the copy of modifying string.